# Network request failed

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

I have a problem with fetch() api, I use get method + https, and in Android 9 doesn't work. In android 7 worked.

Code:

```js
        fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(myJson) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(myJson));
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                alert(error);
            });
```

Screen:
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltfWD.png)

Comment: did you tired my solution ? did it's worked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starting android 9 you must to declare manually to which url's your app can make requests.

If you wish to make fast fix and open your app for all url's just add in you manifest:

```
 <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...
     >
```

For more info take a look [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html)

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: No i mean what is the original error you have? what do you see in error response?